# Finding integers in a txt file

Tags: java, integer

I am trying to read info from a txt file. The text file is in the following format:

```
1 I like programming. 2 "but I am new at it"  3 -so I need to go 
4 on web sites, 5 to get 6 help. 
7 I appreciate any help you could give me. 8 Thanks.
```

I want to display it as follows, while adding "Chap", for chapter, before each number.

```
Chap 1 I like programming. 
Chap 2 "but I am new at it" 
Chap 3 -so I need to go 
Chap 4 on web sites,
Chap 5 to get 
Chap 6 help. 
Chap 7 I appreciate any help you could give me.
Chap 8 Thanks.
```

This is what I have so far:

```
public class ReadAFile {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Get bible book names, chapters and verses
    File fileIn = new File("t.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileIn);                

    while(inputFile.hasNext())
    {
        // Read all lines from the file.
        String line = inputFile.nextLine();
        System.out.println(line);
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");      
        for(int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
        {
            if(tokens[i].matches("^-?\\d+$")) // I'mm using this to try to find the numbers in the txt file
            {
                for(int p = 0; p < tokens.length; p++)
                {
                    System.out.println(tokens[p]);                      
                }       
            }
        }                           
    }           
    inputFile.close();
}   
}
```

The output is not what I am looking for and I can't figure out why. I either get every word on its own line or multiple lines of the the same sentence.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've edited your answer to remove the preamble and thanks in advance as they are considered unnecessary on StackOverflow. I've also added a [tag:Java] tag to help others find/classify your question. If my guess of Java was incorrect, please amend it accordingly. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching the `println` in the for loop to a `print`, and then insert a new line when the Chapter title is printed?

Here is part of your own code, modified.

```
if(tokens[i].matches("^-?\\d+$")) // I'mm using this to try to find the numbers in the txt file
{
    for(int p = 0; p < tokens.length; p++)
    {
        System.out.print(tokens[p]+ " "); //print                    
    }       
    System.out.println()//Empty line
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Will the numbers ALWAYS be consecutive starting at 1? If so, why not use that to your advantage and just change Scanner's delimiter to be the number and replace it with a counter? Something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // Get bible book names, chapters and verses
    File fileIn = new File("t.txt");
    Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(fileIn);
    inputFile.useDelimiter("\\s*-?\\d+\\s*");

    for (int num = 1; inputFile.hasNext(); num++)
    {
        System.out.println("Chap " + num + " " + inputFile.next());
    }

    inputFile.close();
}
```

Output:

```
Chap 1 I like programming.
Chap 2 "but I am new at it"
Chap 3 -so I need to go
Chap 4 on web sites,
Chap 5 to get
Chap 6 help.
Chap 7 I appreciate any help you could give me.
Chap 8 Thanks.
```

If not, let me know and I'll work on something to parse it out and keep it :)

Comment: The numbers will not always be consecutive. The txt file will be:                 1 bla 2 bla 3 bla...                                                                                                    2 bla 2 bla 3 bla 4 bla...                                                                                3 bla 2 bla 3 bla...  this continues until the next chapter is reached.

Comment: So it sounds like it should also search for verses within the chapter too? That would need some kind of additional consistent marker to use for chapters compared to verses as a delimiter no matter what. You'll be able to use that delimiter to nest the loops. If all you have are numbers with no way of telling between chapter & verse numbers, there's no way of splitting or delineating them. Would the chapter numbers be able to have a double line break between them? You can then use two Scanners with "\\n\\n\\s*-?\\d+\\s*" outside and "\\s*-?\\d+\\s*" inside and still count if it's starting at 1.